# Is it a security issue to leave a server path hardcoded in javascript file?

Tags: javascript, security

I need to retrieve to the user of my web app a few images stored in the server folder. To avoid ajax and complicated things, since the number of images to show is little, I was thinking of leaving the paths to the images as hard-coded strings in the js used by the app. This looks to me like the simplest, fastest solution. But is it a security issue? I don't care if the user's downloads those images though, but could a bad guy use the info of the server path for some bad purpose?

Comment: Cons:
- Users can see the path (or full path) of the image location.

Pros:
 - As you said is simple.. What web server are you using? Any framework you are using for JS?

Comment: "_server path_", do you mean you're delivering images outside of the webroot?

Comment: @oetoni 1) Apache 2) If i can stick to pure js better, if not i'll go with jQuery

Comment: @Teemu yes a folder outside the webroot

Comment: I'm bad with servers, but I wouldn't do that. Users can see the full path anyway via the dev tools or various browser functionalities.

Comment: How does the JS (the browser) make use of paths on the server that are outside of the webroot (the URL space)?

Comment: @BabaNew wrote exactly what I had in mind. Yes, that is a straight forward and good solution. Leave the folder outside the web root (maybe httpdocs or www or anything else). That way only internal services can access the files there and use them. Any external approach would be automatically blocked by the webs erver.